# Remix validated form - problem reloading the default values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

I'm using `remix-validated-form` to manage my form containing several input fields.

According to the change event on one select field I reload the route to get the values to fill in the form, which I pass as default values. However, the form is not setting those values properly.

Each time the route reloads the default values are those from the previous request, not the latest one. When I tested it using remix Form it works as expected.

Is there something I'm not doing properly or it may be an issue with the library ?

I made a toy example where you can observe the described behavior: [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/validated-form-default-values-kjn5xk?file=%2Fapp%2Froutes%2Findex.tsx)

This is the loader:

```js
export const loader = async ({request}: LoaderArgs) => {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  const value = url.searchParams.get('select') || '';

  const key = Math.random();
  let values = {select: '', fieldA: '', fieldB: '', key};

  if (value !== '') {
    values = {select: value, fieldA: `${value}-A`, fieldB: `${value}-B`, key};
  }

  return json({values});
};
```

And the route:

```js
export default function RemixValidatedFormRoute() {
  const data = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const {getInputProps: selectProps} = useField('select', {formId: 'fT'});
  const {getInputProps: firstInputProps} = useField('fieldA', {formId: 'fT'});
  const {getInputProps: secondInputProps} = useField('fieldB', {formId: 'fT'});

  const validator = withZod(
    Z.object({select: Z.string(), fieldA: Z.string(), fieldB: Z.string()}),
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <ValidatedForm
        id="fT"
        validator={validator}
        defaultValues={data.values}
        key={data.values.key}
      >
        <select
          {...selectProps({
            id: 'select',
            className: 'select',
            onChange: event => {
              const value = event.target.value;
              navigate(`/test?select=${value}`, {replace: true});
            },
          })}
        >
          <option value=""> Select one</option>
          <option value="1"> First</option>
          <option value="2"> Second</option>
          <option value="3"> Third</option>
        </select>

        <input {...firstInputProps({ id: 'fieldA', className: 'fieldA' })} />
        <input {...secondInputProps({ id: 'fieldB', className: 'fieldB' })} />
      </ValidatedForm>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Notes:

- You can also test how it works using the remix Form (there is a link below the form in the sandbox)
- To reproduce it you can:

  1. select "first" -> the values are loaded but the select does not change.
  2. select "third" -> the select value is updated to "first"
  3. select "second" -> all inputs are updated with the "third" values

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with this approach that you are having. But, you can pass value prop and issue that you are mentioning will be resolved.

You may try like this:

```
export default function RemixValidatedFormRoute() {
  const data = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const {getInputProps: selectProps} = useField('select', {formId: 'fT'});
  const {getInputProps: firstInputProps} = useField('fieldA', {formId: 'fT'});
  const {getInputProps: secondInputProps} = useField('fieldB', {formId: 'fT'});

  const validator = withZod(
    Z.object({select: Z.string(), fieldA: Z.string(), fieldB: Z.string()}),
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <ValidatedForm
        id="fT"
        validator={validator}
        defaultValues={data.values}
        key={data.values.key}
      >
        <select
          {...selectProps({
            id: 'select',
            className: 'select',
            value: data?.values?.select ?? ''
            onChange: (event) => {
              const value = event.target.value;
              navigate(`/test?select=${value}`, {replace: true});
            },
          })}
        >
          <option value=""> Select one</option>
          <option value="1"> First</option>
          <option value="2"> Second</option>
          <option value="3"> Third</option>
        </select>

        <input {...firstInputProps({ id: 'fieldA', value: data?.values?.fieldA ?? '', className: 'fieldA' })} />
        <input {...secondInputProps({ id: 'fieldB', value: data?.values?.fieldB ?? '', className: 'fieldB' })} />
      </ValidatedForm>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The best approach is to handle form submission inside `action` method. Also, there is an option to [setFormDefaults](https://www.remix-validated-form.io/reference/set-form-defaults#setFormDefaults).

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the exact same issue with `remix-validated-form`.

I might have a solution, but I actually don't like it much.

My fix is to create get the FormContext (`useFormContext`) and set ValidatedForm.key to a combination of `data.values.key` and `formContext.defaultValues.select`. Using only one of them does not seem to work:

```
import { withZod } from "@remix-validated-form/with-zod";
import * as Z from "zod";
import { type LoaderArgs, json } from "@remix-run/node";
import { useLoaderData, useNavigate } from "@remix-run/react";
import { ValidatedForm, useField, useFormContext } from "remix-validated-form";

export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderArgs) => {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  const value = url.searchParams.get("select") || "";

  const key = Math.random();
  let values = { select: "", fieldA: "", fieldB: "", key };

  if (value !== "") {
    values = { select: value, fieldA: `${value}-A`, fieldB: `${value}-B`, key };
  }

  return json({ values });
};

export default function RemixValidatedFormRoute() {
  const data = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const formContext = useFormContext("fT");

  const props = { formId: "fT" };
  const { getInputProps: selectProps } = useField("select", props);
  const { getInputProps: firstInputProps } = useField("fieldA", props);
  const { getInputProps: secondInputProps } = useField("fieldB", props);

  const validator = withZod(
    Z.object({ select: Z.string(), fieldA: Z.string(), fieldB: Z.string() })
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <ValidatedForm
        id="fT"
        validator={validator}
        defaultValues={data.values}
        key={`${data.values.key}-${formContext.defaultValues?.select}`}
      >
        <select
          {...selectProps({
            id: "select",
            className: "select",
            onChange: (event) => {
              navigate(`?select=${event.target.value}`, { replace: true });
            },
          })}
        >
          <option value=""> Select one</option>
          <option value="1"> First</option>
          <option value="2"> Second</option>
          <option value="3"> Third</option>
        </select>

        <input {...firstInputProps({ id: "fieldA", className: "fieldA" })} />
        <input {...secondInputProps({ id: "fieldB", className: "fieldB" })} />
      </ValidatedForm>

      <br />
      <a href="/remixForm">Test with remix Form </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```